# Django day and time picker

Tags: html, django, calendar

I'm trying to build my first website with django,I've accomplished user registration and login so far but now I'm stuck: I want to show to the users a weekly calendar where they can pick a day and book a gym class. 
I tried to handle every week day like a form field but it didn't work.

Any advice on how I should tackle this?

I'm looking for something like an explanation/a tutorial and would avoid a github project, if possible.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
Alrigth, thanks to the answers i got ,i did this:
1.I register the new users in forms.py in an application called register:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name=forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name=forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=forms.EmailField()
    mobile=forms.CharField(max_length=13)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=['username','first_name','last_name','email','mobile','password1', 'password2']
```

2.Create a new application called reservation where in models i tried to build a new database

```
from django.db import models
from register import forms
import datetime


class Booking(models.Model):
    class_name = models.ForeignKey('Class', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = forms.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="bookings")
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    selected_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)


class Class(models.Model):
     class_time=models.DateTimeField()
     class_day=models.DateField()
     MIN_PEOPLE = 2 #not less than 2 people each class
     MAX_PEOPLE = 12 #not more than 12 allowed
```

But here i got this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'register.forms' has no attribute 'ForeignKey'
```

3.In reservation i made a html page called reservation.html where i put my calender where i wish the user will pick a day, a class time and book it

```
<!-- Class Time Section Begin -->
<section class="classtime-section class-time-table spad">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h2>Orario Classi</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="classtime-table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Lunedì</th>
                        <th>Martedì</th>
                        <th>Mercoledì</th>
                        <th>Giovedì</th>
                        <th>Venerdì</th>
                        <th>Sabato</th>
                        <th>Domenica</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="workout-time">10.00</td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="crossfit">
                            <span>10.00 - 14.00</span>
                            <h6>Crossfit lezione</h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="crossfit">
                            <span>10.00 - 15.00</span>
                            <h6>Crossfit lezione</h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="lunge">
                            <span>10.00 - 13.00</span>
                            <h6>Mobility</h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="lunge">
                            <span>10.00 - 13.30</span>
                            <h6>Mobility</h6>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="workout-time">14.00</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="lunge">
                            <span>14.00 - 17.00</span>
                            <h6>Weight lifting</h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="crossfit">
                            <span>14.00 - 17.00</span>
                            <h6>Crossfit lezione</h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="walls">
                            <span>14.00 - 15.30</span>
                            <h6>Mobility</h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="workout-time">16.00</td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="lunge">
                            <span>16.00 - 18.00</span>
                            <h6>Lezione</h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="candy">
                            <span>16.00 - 19.00</span>
                            <h6>Lezione</h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="candy">
                            <span>16.00 - 19.00</span>

                        </td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="ppsr">
                            <span>16.00 - 17.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="murph">
                            <span>16.00 - 20.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="workout-time">18.00</td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="walls">
                            <span>18.00 - 20.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="ppsr">
                            <span>18.00 - 20.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="chelsea">
                            <span>18.00 - 22.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="annie">
                            <span>18.00 - 22.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="workout-time">20.00</td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="lunge">
                            <span>21.00 - 23.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="walls">
                            <span>20.00 - 22.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="walls">
                            <span>20.30 - 23.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="crossfit">
                            <span>22.00 - 23.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="hover-bg ts-item" data-tsmeta="crossfit">
                            <span>21.00 - 23.00</span>
                            <h6></h6>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- Class Time Section End -->
```

The thing is: i have no idea how to connect the reservation.html to the database in reservation/models.py and the User model with the booking class.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a model (or use an existing one, e.g. Profile if you have) - refer to the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/

Then you have a specific field to pick the day and time, using DateTimeField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

In order to get a date picker, there are a number of options you can use. I did the following, which worked quite well. In my users app in forms.py, I added the following:

```
class DateTimeInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
       input_type = 'date_time'
```

And then under your Meta class for your ProfileForm:

```
widgets = {
         'date_time': DateTimeInput(),
               }
```

For details on this, refer to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/

Give it a go, see how far you get and if you run in to issues, update your question.

Comment: i tried to follow your flow and read the documentation but as you can see in the edited part of my answer i got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to re-invent the wheel. Django can deliver a built-in date and time picker. Since We can't see the code you are working with, I'll make some assumptions:

Let's assume you have a database model called Bookings

```
# models.py

import datetime

class Booking(models.Model):
    class_name = models.ForeignKey('Class', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="bookings")
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    selected_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

Then when you create your Form on the front end, use Django's built-in Form templates (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/)

```
#myapp/forms.py

from django import forms

class BookingForm(BookingForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('class_name', 'selected_datetime ')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['class_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'formInputs'
        self.fields['class_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Class Name'
        self.fields['class_name'].label = 'Class Name'

        self.fields['selected_datetime '].widget.attrs['class'] = 'formInputs'
        self.fields['selected_datetime '].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Select a class time'
        self.fields['selected_datetime '].label = 'Select a class time'
```

The Views.py file would look something like this:

```
#views.py

from myapp.forms import BookingForm
from api.models import Booking

def choose_class(request):
    form = BookingForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # this is where you would handle the returned data, and save it to the database 
        class_name = request.POST['class_name']
        selected_datetime = request.POST['selected_datetime ']
        Booking.objects.create(class_name = class_name, selected_datetime=selected_datetime)

    return render(request, 'choose_class.html', {'form':form})
```

Then your HTML template would look something like this:

```
#choose_class.html

{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}


<div class="chooseClass">
    <h4 class="text-center">Choose Class</h4>

    <form class="chooseClassForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'choose_class' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <p>Oops! Please double check the following errors:</p>
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% if field.errors %}
                        {{ field.errors }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Choose that class" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Anyways, there is a bit more to it than that, but since you didn't give us much to work with, that's what I'll provide for now, and this is untested code, there are likely some errors since I didn't write it in an IDE first.
hopefully, that helps!

Comment: I tried to implement your class in model.py but i got an error.